# C# mvc angular $rngRoute $http.get mixed up

Tags: c#, angularjs, ngroute

I have implement code to return some data from C# MVC controller to the .cshtml file (works pretty well).

```
var AnimalApp = angular.module('AnimalApp', []);
AnimalApp.controller('AnimalController', function ($scope, AnimalService) {
    getAnimals();
    function getAnimals() {
        AnimalService.getAnimals()
            .success(function (studs) {
                $scope.animals = studs;
            })

            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load animal data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }
});

AnimalApp.factory('AnimalService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var AnimalService = {};
    AnimalService.getAnimals = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetData');
    };
    return AnimalService;
}]);
```

Here is the C# controller that returns the data:

```
public JsonResult GetData(string keyword)
{
    AnimalDBContext db = new AnimalDBContext();
    var result = db.Animals.ToList();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my C# controller to return the view:

```
public ActionResult giorgos ()
    {
    return View();
    }
```

Although, when I call this templateUrl from the ngRoute, even the page appear, data DO NOT.

Here is the code that I am talking about:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
       templateUrl: "/Home/Create"
   })
    .when("/listing", {
        templateUrl: "/Home/GetData"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl: "/Home/giorgos"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "/Home/About"
    });
});
```

Again: when I load the page itself, data appear. But when I load the page from the $rngRoute function, data do not....

Any help is welcome!

Comment: what is `$rngRoute`?

Comment: You're mixing. ngRoute is not ui-Router. RTFM: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Even if I do,  why the other templates appear but the one I say don't? Actually it appears too, but without receiving the data

Answer (score 0):

Notice that what I get from the browser console is

"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AnimalController' is not a function, got undefined